# ValueError : The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm getting this error when I shifted my code from  Django 1.9 to django 2.2.9 version. It's perfectly working in django 1.9 but Can Anyone tell what has changed in 2.2.9 for this specific search. [This is the Error I'm getting, I am stuck. I tried django doc. help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJF4n.png)

```
def search(request):
    locations = Location.objects.all()#.order_by('location_name')
    departments = Department.objects.all()#.order_by('department_name')
    if not request.GET.get('location', 'none') == 'none' and not request.GET.get('specialty', 'none') == 'none':
        location = request.GET.get('location',None)
        specialty = request.GET.get('specialty',None)
        location = Location.objects.filter(location_name=location)
        hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(location=location)
        # doctors = DoctorProfile.objects.filter(user.first_name__contains=first_name)
        doctors = []

        for hospital in hospitals:
            specialty = Department.objects.filter(department_name=specialty)
            doctors = DoctorProfile.objects.filter(hospital=hospital, specialization=specialty)

        return render(request, 'infrastructure/search.html', {'doctors': doctors, 'locations': locations, 'departments': departments})

    return render(request, 'infrastructure/search.html', {'locations': locations, 'departments': departments})
```

Answer (score 2):

`location` is a *collection* of `Location` objects. That collection can contain zero, one, or more elements, but it is still a collection.

In order to retrieve the hospitals, you can use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
location = Location.objects.filter(location_name=location)
hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(location__in=location)
```

or you can filter on the related model:

```
location = Location.objects.filter(location_name=location)
hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(location__location_name=location)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I figured out that I was passing location and specialty as a Query set. adding [0] with it makes it object. And with that It worked fine.

here is the code:

```
location = Location.objects.filter(location_name=location)[0]
hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(location=location)

doctors = []

for hospital in hospitals:
    specialty = Department.objects.filter(department_name=specialty)[0]
    doctors=DoctorProfile.objects.filter(hospital=hospital, specialization=specialty)
```

Thanks For your help!!